# Progress Dialog in findInBackground for parse Database without using Thread or AsynchTaks

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

Can any one guide me how can i show progress dialog while fetching data from parse data base. Thanks

```
    public void fetch() {

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Phrase");
    try {
        query.setLimit(1000);

        progress_Dialog.setTitle("Parse Library Download");

        progress_Dialog.setMessage("Downloading Please wait....");

        progress_Dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);

        progress_Dialog.show();

        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void done(List<ParseObject> greeting_list, ParseException e) {

                                       parse_count = greeting_list.size();

                                       if (e == null) {
                                           for (ParseObject obj : greeting_list) {


                                               image_file = obj.getParseFile("image");

                                               try {
                                                   bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image_file.getData(), 0, image_file.getData().length);

                                                   bmp = getResizedBitmap(bmp, 500, 500);

                                                   ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                                                   bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);

                                                   image_array = stream.toByteArray();
                                               } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                                   e1.printStackTrace();
                                               }

                                               audioFile = obj.getParseFile("audio");

                                               try {
                                                   counter = dBhelper.insert_TextData(obj.getString("english"), obj.getString("italian"), image_array, audioFile.getData(), obj.getString("category"));

                                                   System.out.println(counter);

                                                   progress_Dialog.setProgress(progressStatus);

                                                   progressStatus++;


                                               } catch (ParseException e1) {
                                                   e1.printStackTrace();
                                               }
                                           }
                                           progress_Dialog.dismiss();

                                           System.out.println("ALL DATA FETCHED");

                                       } else {

                                           Log.d("Error", "" + e.getMessage());
                                           e.printStackTrace();
                                       }
                                   }
                               }
        );
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Show what u have tried?

Comment: my progress.Setprogress method is not working i will code below you can have look please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ParseQuery to retrieve this data. Read Parse's Android Guide on using [Queries](https://parse.com/docs/android/guide#queries)

With progress dialog use asyntask check below example :

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create a progressdialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        // Set progressdialog title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Parse.com Custom ListView Tutorial");
        // Set progressdialog message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        // Show progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        worldpopulationlist = new ArrayList<WorldPopulation>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "Country");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("ranknum");
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject country : ob) {
                // Locate images in flag column
                ParseFile image = (ParseFile) country.get("flag");

                WorldPopulation map = new WorldPopulation();
                map.setRank((String) country.get("rank"));
                map.setCountry((String) country.get("country"));
                map.setPopulation((String) country.get("population"));
                map.setFlag(image.getUrl());
                worldpopulationlist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
        listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new ListViewAdapter(MainActivity.this,
                worldpopulationlist);
        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
        // Close the progressdialog
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer i successfully fetched data but i need to know how to show progress dialog with progress while fetching data from parse data base. Thanks

Comment: Chirag Thanks a lot for your help i really appreciate you help you are a life save i was struggling with this problem for a while now finally done it with your help.